# how to define the value of a variable in an interface slider instead of agent initialization?

Tags: netlogo

I got this variable called `flip-rate`.

```
globals [
  magnetization
]

turtles-own [
  opinion
  flip-rate
  temp-opinion
]

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;;;;;;;;;; AGENT INITIALIZATION ;;;;;;;;;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

to initialize-hvm ;; turtle procedure
  ask turtles [
    set opinion one-of n-values number-states [ ?1 -> ?1 ]
    recolor
    set flip-rate random-float 1
  ]
  set-magnetization
end
```

instead of having this flip-rate variable set as a random value in agent initialization, how do I set with a slider on the interface section?

I tried moving the flip-rate variable to

```
globals
```

but when I try to create a slider with the same name, I get an error saying "There is already a global variable called FLIP-RATE".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The slider itself is a global variable (see [here](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/interfacetab.html#sliders)). So you don't have to define it in the code tab. Assuming you have named your slider `flip-rate-slider`, you can use it to assign it's value to the turtles-own variable `flip-rate`:

```
globals [
  magnetization
]

turtles-own [
  opinion
  flip-rate
  temp-opinion
]

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;;;;;;;;;; AGENT INITIALIZATION ;;;;;;;;;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

to initialize-hvm ;; turtle procedure
  ask turtles [
    set opinion one-of n-values number-states [ ?1 -> ?1 ]
    recolor
    set flip-rate flip-rate-slider
  ]
  set-magnetization
end
```

Comment: thank you! this helped a lot in moving forward with my project